# Tetrode versus Common Gate Depletion mode MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, depletion-mode

I've been looking at all the specification sheets for N-channel tetrodes. What is of particular interest is the old 3N213 by GE.

Are all Tetrodes nothing more than dual gate (common gate) N-channel depletion mode transistors with both transistors sharing a common gate? Which brings up a second question: My understanding is that these transistors are made from monolithic chips (the gates are electrically common or shared). Is that correct? If I connect/bond two discrete chips at their gates, does that make the device a tetrode?

Comment: In what way would you "bond" two transistors? || Dual-gates act more like a cascode pair, FYI.

Comment: @periblepsis The tetrode FET has nothing to do with tetrode vacuum tubes, and the question isn't asking about vacuum tubes.

Comment: There would be a common gate pin that would  send a signal to 2 gates at the same time for the 2 transistors .  RCA called the 3N213 a Dual N Channel Depletion Mode Tetrodes .